# Channel's Status 'Disabled'

Tags: slack, botframework

What would cause channels added to BotFramework's Console for its status to be set to 'Disabled'?

We suddenly experienced this (during a demo) out of nowhere but there were no changes since we've added that to BotFramework's Console.

Here is a capture of the console,
[image]

I've only seen its status as either 'Running' or 'Error', however, this is the first time this occurred. I tried re-authenticating to now avail. Slack authentications works.

Tested the `/messages` API, I am able to send a message, however, the bot won't still go online and status is still set to 'Disabled' even after enabling/disabling the option in the console.

To add, I've tried create a new bot on a new BotFramework account to no avail and the status is still the same.

I've already tried regenerating my Slack secret, still the same

Comment: Tried reverting back to `SlackBot` with `botkit` this morning and its working fine, so there is a problem in either BotConnector or the botframework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service is again running today. As per @tomlm from BotFramework Team.

> We had a bad setting get on our server which impeded the autoscale/alerting system. It has been fixed and things should be stable now. Sorry for the down-time.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/490#issuecomment-227055543)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Slack channel doesn't work at all at the moment: my bots don't respond too (although their status is "Running"). I also tried BuildBot (from Bot Directory), but it also works properly on all channels except slack.

All those bots from botframework have status "away". I hope it would be fixed soon.